# Publish Console App

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, console-application

After I publish using Visual Studio 2013 and run the file, it gives me an error... It is not accepting inputs from the command line like it should be. I am sure the error is on my end, considering I am so new to publishing apps this way. Any Help is greatly appreciated. I posted the code for the main method below ... If more would be helpful, please let me know

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DBAccessManager DBAccess = new DBAccessManager();
    SqlConnection connString = new SqlConnection();

    connString.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
        .ConnectionStrings["HeatConnection"].ToString();

    if(args.Length != 0 && IsOnlyInts(args[0])){
        if(args[1] == "true")
        {
            string UserId = "US" + args[0];
            SearchResult result = DBAccessManager
                .ReadActiveDirectoryEntry(UserId);
            DBAccess.UpdateSQL(connString.ConnectionString, result, UserId);
        }
        else
        {
            Employee SQLresult = DBAccess.ReadUserInformation(
                connString.ConnectionString.ToString(), args[0])[0];

            if (SQLresult != null)
            {
                string LdapServerName = "ServerName";
                DBAccess.UpdateActiveDirectory(LdapServerName, args[0], 
                    SQLresult);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Customer Id Not Found.");
            }
        }
    }       
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Customer id number must be provided. Only Numbers are allowed");
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to Continue");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error? What line does it occur on?

Comment: if you have only one argument you'll throw an error

Comment: Why publish a console app? Why not just run the exe? Just curious

Comment: And please include your using statements

Comment: Google "clickonce command line parameters".  First hit already looks good.

Comment: I apologize for not getting back to this sooner... I forgot I had posted this. One way or the other... I have been waiting for the network admin to get back to me on some questions regarding this and haven't heard back yet. I will post back on this once I hear back from him...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After waiting and waiting, the project requirements changed. So this is no longer a relevant question anymore... I am marking this as the answer so it's not seen as needing an answer